# Getting nan training cost in keras multivariate NN

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

I'm training a NN to have 6 inputs and 2 outputs. I'm using Keras with a Tensorflow backend. After preprocessing, this is my code:

```
training_examples = features.head(2584)
training_targets = targets.head(2584)

validation_examples = features.tail(650)
validation_targets = targets.tail(650)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=6))
model.add(Dense(8))
model.add(Dense(8))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd')
print("Training--------")
for step in range(500):
  cost = model.train_on_batch(training_examples, training_targets)
  if step % 100 == 0:
    print('train cost: ', cost)
```

Every time I run this is results in an output like

```
Training--------
train cost:  6670.4097
train cost:  nan
train cost:  nan
train cost:  nan
train cost:  nan
```

The first training cost keeps varying somewhere between 2000 - 14000 usually. The features and targets are all less than 100 numerically. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Edit: I added `features.info()` and `targets.info()` to check for null values, there are no null values in the dataframes.

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3231 entries, 0 to 3230
Data columns (total 6 columns):
TBRG_Rain_infield    3231 non-null float64
numRange_infield     3231 non-null float64
Air_T_edge           3231 non-null float64
RH_edge              3231 non-null float64
TBRG_Rain_edge       3231 non-null float64
numRange_edge        3231 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(6)
memory usage: 176.7 KB
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3231 entries, 0 to 3230
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Air_T    3231 non-null float64
RH       3231 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 75.7 KB`

Comment: Are your examples pandas dataframes? Did you check for any NaNs there?

Comment: My examples are dataframes. There are no NaNs in `features` or `targets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataframes look correct, but you should probably scale your input features to be between 0 and 1 or to have mean 0 and unit variance. I tried to reproduce your example, once with and once without scaling.

Without scaling:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

features = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(1000, 6)).astype(float))
targets = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000, 2), dtype=np.float64)

training_examples = features.head(100)  
training_targets = targets.tail(100)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=6))
model.add(Dense(8))
model.add(Dense(8))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd')
print("Training--------")
for step in range(500):
    cost = model.train_on_batch(training_examples, training_targets)
    if step % 100 == 0:
        print('train cost: ', cost)
```

Gives as output:

```
Training--------
train cost:  6834.277
train cost:  nan
train cost:  nan
train cost:  nan
train cost:  nan
```

If I initialize the features to be between 0 and 1 however:

```
features = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000, 6), dtype=np.float64)
```

This is the output:

```
Training--------
train cost:  1.1240386
train cost:  0.09793612
train cost:  0.08868038
train cost:  0.084703445
train cost:  0.0826226
```

You can have a look at the [StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) from scikit-learn to scale your data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm looking into StandardScaler right now

Comment: That worked. However, how do I scale the values back up to get the real predictions which should've been?

Comment: The StandardScaler has an `inverse_transform` method. See [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.inverse_transform) :)